# Magento2.4.2: How to create two images field in admin form?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to one more image field in my custom admin form
[image]

This is my custom admin form
and i want to add one more image field and my code is this

> vendor/PromotionsPopUpBox/view/adminhtml/ui_component/promotions_form.xml

```
<fieldset name="promotions_popup_box">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">PopUpBox Form</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Description</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/preview</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="promotions/form/tempUpload"/>
                    </item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[Allowed file types:jpg, jpeg, png.]]></item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="category_link">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Link</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_link</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="timer" formElement="date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">timer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Timer</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <dataScope>timer</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
```

> \Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form\TempUpload.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface as UrlInterfaceAlias;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class TempUpload extends Action
{

    /**
     *
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    protected UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;

    /**
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|Json|ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $jsonResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        try {
            $fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $fileUploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $fileUploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $fileUploader->validateFile();
            $result = $fileUploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('tmp/imageUploader/images'));
            $result['url'] = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterfaceAlias::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)
                . 'tmp/imageUploader/images/' . ltrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $result['file']), '/');
            return $jsonResult->setData($result);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $jsonResult->setData(['errorcode' => 0, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            error_log($e->getTraceAsString());
            return $jsonResult->setData([
                'errorcode' => 0,
                'error' => __(
                    'An error occurred, please try again later.'
                )
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> \Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form\Save.php
> ```

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Validation\ValidationException;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\FormInterfaceFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Api\FormRepositoryInterface;

class Save extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var FormInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected FormInterfaceFactory $formInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var FormRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected FormRepositoryInterface $formRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    protected UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param FormRepositoryInterface $formRepositoryInterface
     * @param FormInterfaceFactory $formInterfaceFactory
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        FormRepositoryInterface $formRepositoryInterface,
        FormInterfaceFactory $formInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->formInterfaceFactory = $formInterfaceFactory;
        $this->formRepositoryInterface = $formRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function execute(): ResponseInterface
    {
        try {
            if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'POST'
                || !$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid Request'));
            }

            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            if (isset($params['entity_id'])) {
                $imageName = $params['image'][0];
                $data = $this->formRepositoryInterface->getById($params['entity_id']);
                if (isset($imageName['tmp_name'])) {
                    $info = $this->validateImage($params);
                    $this->saveRow($info, $params, $data);
                } else {
                    $data->setTitle($params['title']);
                    $data->setDescription($params['description']);
                    $data->setCategoryLink($params['category_link']);
                    $data->setTimer($params['timer']);
                    $this->formRepositoryInterface->save($data);
                    return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/1/');
                }
            } else {
                $info = $this->validateImage($params);
                $image = $this->formInterfaceFactory->create();
                $this->saveRow($info, $params, $image);
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/1/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            error_log($e->getTraceAsString());
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An error occurred, please try again later.'));
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/1/');
        }
        return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/1/');
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function validateImage($params)
    {
        try {
            $fileUploader = null;
            $imageId = 'image';
            if (isset($params['image']) && count($params['image'])) {
                $imageId = $params['image'][0];
                if (!file_exists($imageId['tmp_name'])) {
                    $imageId['tmp_name'] = $imageId['path'] . '/' . $imageId['file'];
                }
            }
            $fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $imageId]);
            $fileUploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $fileUploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $fileUploader->validateFile();
            return $fileUploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('imageUploader/images'));
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            throw new
            LocalizedException(__(
                'Image extension is not supported. Only extensions allowed are jpg, jpeg and png'
            ));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //if an except is thrown, no image has been uploaded
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Image is required'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @throws CouldNotSaveException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveRow($info, $params, $data): ResponseInterface
    {
        try {

            $data->setTitle($params['title']);
            $data->setDescription($params['description']);
            $data->setImage($this->mediaDirectory->getRelativePath('imageUploader/images') . '/' . $info['file']);
            $data->setCategoryLink($params['category_link']);
            $data->setTimer($params['timer']);
            $data->setStatus($params['status']);

            $this->formRepositoryInterface->save($data);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Promotions saved successfully'));
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/1/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //if an except is thrown, no image has been uploaded
            throw new LocalizedException(__("Form didn't save"));
        }
    }
}
```

**If i follow the same approach i followed for one image then there will be two much duplicated code.
and there is enough duplicate code in this**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the XML needs to be duplicated, and even for that only the relevant field. Just add another element of the same type, with the relevant values changed, right next to (below) this code:

```
    <field name="image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/preview</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="promotions/form/tempUpload"/>
                </item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[Allowed file types:jpg, jpeg, png.]]></item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

As for the PHP, you can wrap all the logic in functions and invoke them with the field name in a parameter. You don't need to duplicate the files, just the code specific to the field.

## Requested examples

Here would be your updated XML:

```
    <field name="image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/preview</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="promotions/form/tempUpload"/>
                </item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[Allowed file types:jpg, jpeg, png.]]></item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="image_2">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image 2</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/preview</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="string">jpg jpeg gif png svg</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="promotions/form/tempUpload"/>
                </item>
                <item name="notice" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[Allowed file types:jpg, jpeg, png.]]></item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Here would be your updated PHP `Controller\Adminhtml\Form\TempUpload.php` file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface as UrlInterfaceAlias;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class TempUpload extends Action {

    /** @var UploaderFactory */
    protected UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory;

    /** @var Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface */
    protected Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory;

    /** @var StoreManagerInterface */
    protected StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;

    /** @throws FileSystemException */
    public function __construct(Context $context, UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory, Filesystem $filesystem, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|Json|ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $images = ['image', 'image_2'];
        $return_vals = [];
        foreach ($images as $img) {
            $return_vals[] = uploadSpecificImage(string $img);
        }

        // Decide what you want to return here.
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|Json|ResultInterface
     */
    public function uploadSpecificImage(string $image)
    {
        $jsonResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        try {
            $fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $image]);
            $fileUploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $fileUploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $fileUploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $fileUploader->validateFile();
            $result = $fileUploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('tmp/imageUploader/images'));
            $result['url'] = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterfaceAlias::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)
                . 'tmp/imageUploader/images/' . ltrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $result['file']), '/');
            return $jsonResult->setData($result);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            return $jsonResult->setData(['errorcode' => 0, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            error_log($e->getTraceAsString());
            return $jsonResult->setData([
                'errorcode' => 0,
                'error' => __(
                    'An error occurred, please try again later.'
                )
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that, as requested, this is **example code** that I wrote in the SO editor, not PHP that I've rigorously tested.

Comment: can you show some example?

Comment: What about the save file, it really needs to be refactor

Comment: Yes, I agree. Use the **example code** to wrap the critical parts of the save file just list was done with the TempUpload file, and run a foreach() for each image field name.

Comment: thanks, but i followed a simple aproach for just two images, kindly see if its needs refactoring or is it good to go, if not where i can improve it?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Instead of `$imageId = 'image';`, use a foreach over an array to get each imageId. You're on the right track, and you've managed to do it yourself!

Comment: i now understand your logic and will try to do it your way, its better with a loop

Comment: i forgot about edit form functionality, when i click edit it displays second image in form, not both

Comment: That's likely due to accidentally reusing the old image name for the new image field. Go over the XML again, that's usually where this type of typo occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138556/discussion-between-p-a-and-dotancohen).

Comment: just one question, is it possible to upload multiple images just using one input field?

Comment: One input field could support only one image, however, there is nothing preventing you from storing that one image to multiple places. They would all be the same, identical image, though.

Answer (score 1):

> \Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form\TempUpload.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface as UrlInterfaceAlias;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class TempUpload extends Action
{

    /**
     *
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    protected UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;

    /**
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|Json|ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
{
    $files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
    $jsonResult = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    if ($files['image_two']) {
        $field = $files['image_two'];
    } else {
        if ($files['image']) {
            $field = $files['image'];
        }
    }
    try {
        $fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $field]);
        $fileUploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);
        $fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $fileUploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
        $fileUploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $fileUploader->validateFile();
        $result = $fileUploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('tmp/imageUploader/images'));
        $result['url'] = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(UrlInterfaceAlias::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)
            . 'tmp/imageUploader/images/' . ltrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $result['file']), '/');
        return $jsonResult->setData($result);
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        return $jsonResult->setData(['errorcode' => 0, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        error_log($e->getTraceAsString());
        return $jsonResult->setData([
            'errorcode' => 0,
            'error' => __(
                'An error occurred, please try again later.'
            )
        ]);
    }
}
}
```

> ```
> \Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form\Save.php
> ```

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Form;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Validation\ValidationException;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\FormInterfaceFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Api\FormRepositoryInterface;

class Save extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var FormInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected FormInterfaceFactory $formInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var FormRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected FormRepositoryInterface $formRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @var UploaderFactory
     */
    protected UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param FormRepositoryInterface $formRepositoryInterface
     * @param FormInterfaceFactory $formInterfaceFactory
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        FormRepositoryInterface $formRepositoryInterface,
        FormInterfaceFactory $formInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->formInterfaceFactory = $formInterfaceFactory;
        $this->formRepositoryInterface = $formRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function execute(): ResponseInterface
    {
        try {
            if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'POST'
                || !$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid Request'));
            }

            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $imageId = 'image';

            if (isset($params['entity_id'])) {
                $imageNameOne = $params['image'][0];
                $imageNameTwo = $params['image_two'][0];
                $data = $this->formRepositoryInterface->getById($params['entity_id']);
                if (isset($imageNameOne['tmp_name'])) {

                    if (isset($params['image']) && count($params['image'])) {
                        $imageId = $params['image'][0];
                        if (isset($imageId['tmp_name'])) {
                            $imageId['tmp_name'] = $imageId['path'] . '/' . $imageId['file'];
                            $info1 = $this->validateImage($params, $imageId);

                        }
                    }

                    $this->saveRow($info1, $info2 = null, $params, $data);
                } else {
                    if (isset($imageNameTwo['tmp_name'])) {

                        if (isset($params['image_two']) && count($params['image_two'])) {
                            $imageId = $params['image_two'][0];
                            if (isset($imageId['tmp_name'])) {
                                $imageId['tmp_name'] = $imageId['path'] . '/' . $imageId['file'];
                                $info2 = $this->validateImage($params, $imageId);

                            }
                        }
                        $this->saveRow($info1 = null, $info2, $params, $data);

                    } else {
                        $data->setTitle($params['title']);
                        $data->setDescription($params['description']);
                        $data->setCategoryLink($params['category_link']);
                        $data->setTimer($params['timer']);
                        $data->setStatus($params['status']);
                        $this->formRepositoryInterface->save($data);
                        return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/7/');
                    }
                }
            } else {

                if (isset($params['image']) && count($params['image'])) {
                    $imageId = $params['image'][0];
                    if (isset($imageId['tmp_name'])) {
                        $imageId['tmp_name'] = $imageId['path'] . '/' . $imageId['file'];
                        $info1 = $this->validateImage($params, $imageId);

                    }
                }
                if (isset($params['image_two']) && count($params['image_two'])) {
                    $imageId = $params['image_two'][0];
                    if (isset($imageId['tmp_name'])) {
                        $imageId['tmp_name'] = $imageId['path'] . '/' . $imageId['file'];
                        $info2 = $this->validateImage($params, $imageId);

                    }
                }
                $image = $this->formInterfaceFactory->create();
                $this->saveRow($info1, $info2, $params, $image);
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/7/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            error_log($e->getTraceAsString());
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('An error occurred, please try again later.'));
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/7/');
        }
        return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/7/');
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function validateImage($params, $imageId)
    {
        try {
            $fileUploader = null;

            $fileUploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $imageId]);
            $fileUploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);
            $fileUploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $fileUploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
            $fileUploader->validateFile();
            return $fileUploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('imageUploader/images'));
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            throw new
            LocalizedException(__(
                'Image extension is not supported. Only extensions allowed are jpg, jpeg and png'
            ));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //if an except is thrown, no image has been uploaded
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Image is required'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @throws CouldNotSaveException
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveRow($info1, $info2, $params, $data): ResponseInterface
    {
        try {

            $data->setTitle($params['title']);
            $data->setDescription($params['description']);
            if ($info1 != null) {
                $data->setImage($this->mediaDirectory->getRelativePath('imageUploader/images') . '/' . $info1['file']);
            }
            if ($info2 != null) {
                $data->setImageTwo($this->mediaDirectory
                        ->getRelativePath('imageUploader/images') . '/' . $info2['file']);
            }
            $data->setCategoryLink($params['category_link']);
            $data->setTimer($params['timer']);
            $data->setStatus($params['status']);

            $this->formRepositoryInterface->save($data);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Promotions saved successfully'));
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/form/entity_id/7/');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //if an except is thrown, no image has been uploaded
            throw new LocalizedException(__("Form didn't save"));
        }
    }
}
```

> \Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\DataProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Form\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param array $loadedData
     */
    protected array $loadedData;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $postCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getData(): array
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        $this->loadedData = [];
        foreach ($items as $form) {
            $this->loadedData[$form->getData('entity_id')] = $form->getData();
            if ($form->getImage()) {
                $image['image'][0]['name'] = $form->getImage();
                $image['image'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl() . $form->getImage();
                $image['image'][0]['type'] = 'image';

                $fullData = $this->loadedData;
                $this->loadedData[$form->getEntityId()] = array_merge($fullData[$form->getEntityId()], $image);
            }
            if ($form->getImageTwp()) {
                $image2['image_two'][0]['name'] = $form->getImageTwo();
                $image2['image_two'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl() . $form->getImageTwo();
                $image2['image_two'][0]['type'] = 'image';

                $fullData = $this->loadedData;
                $this->loadedData[$form->getEntityId()] = array_merge($fullData[$form->getEntityId()], $image2);
            }
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }

    /**
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getMediaUrl(): string
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    }
}
```